# What is the question tag for sentences whose subjects are "none...is" and "each...is"?

Tags: grammatical-number, negation, question-tags, agreement, grammatical-gender

I know that  indefinite pronouns like *none* and *each* take singular verbs, but what about their question tags?

> 1. None of the boys has passed the test, ________?
> 2. Each of the girls was given a prize, _______?

What are the question tags for these two sentences? Should the question tag’s verb be in the singular like the subject or plural because we’re talking about all of them?

What about that question tag’s pronoun? Would gender come into consideration?

Comment: (1) _, have they?_ (2) _, weren't they?_

Comment: In (1), I would use *None of the boys **have** passed the test,* ***have they***? (The example sentence incorrectly uses *has*.) And In (2), I would use *Each of the girls **was** given a prize,* ***wasn't she?***

Comment: none means no one so it takes a singular verb.none of the boys has passed the test is correct.why can't we use the question tag has n't he?